# Why did Community ♦ review my suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I suggested an edit to the [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles) tag on the main site. It was approved by two human reviewers, but also by the Community ♦ bot:

[image: Screenshot of review results]

Why is it that Community accepted the edit?
I also see that it has rejected 4 and approved 38 – how does it decide how and when to judge edits?

Comment: See this post on meta stackoverflow - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an edit is suggested, a reviewer can choose to improve the edit. If the reviewer checks the box "the suggested edit was helpful", Community approves the suggested edit and the reviewer's edit is also made. If the "the suggested edit was helpful" box is is unchecked, the edit is rejected by Community and the reviewer's edit is made.